# Using filter with each on lodash

Tags: json, lodash

I have this JSON string

```
[
  {
    uri : '/someuri/one',
    title : 'Title 1',
    displayLocation : 'ACTION_MENU',
    masterData : 'LOCATION',
    iconClass : 'icon-class-1'
  }, 
  {
    uri : '/someuri/two',
    title : 'Title 2',
    displayLocation : 'ACTION_MENU',
    masterData : 'LOCATION',
    iconClass : 'icon-class-2'
  },
  {
    uri : '/someuri/three',
    title : 'Title 3',
    displayLocation : 'ACTION_MENU',
    masterData : 'JOB',
    iconClass : 'icon-class-3'
  },
  {
    uri : '/someuri/four',
    title : 'Title 4',
    displayLocation : 'SUMMARY',
    masterData : 'LOCATION',
    iconClass : 'icon-class-4'
  }
]
```

I am converting it to

```
[
  {
    iconClass : 'icon-class-1',
    id : 'anythingUnique',
    text : 'Title 1'
  }, 
  {
    iconClass : 'icon-class-2',
    id : 'anythingUnique',
    text : 'Title 2'
  }
]
```

using following code

```
function myCustomFilter(inputJSONStr) {
  return _.each(inputJSONStr.filter(function(action){
    return action.masterData === 'LOCATION' && action.displayLocation === 'ACTION_MENU';
  }), function (action) {
    return [{iconClass: action.iconClass, id: 'anythingUnique', text: action.title}];
});
```

But its returning me JSON string

```
[
  {
    uri : '/someuri/one',
    title : 'Title 1',
    displayLocation : 'ACTION_MENU',
    masterData : 'LOCATION',
    iconClass : 'icon-class-1'
  },
  {
    uri : '/someuri/two',
    title : 'Title 2',
    displayLocation : 'ACTION_MENU',
    masterData : 'LOCATION',
    iconClass : 'icon-class-2'
  }
]
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use map to do this:

```
_(inputJSONStr).filter({masterData: 'LOCATION', displayLocation: 'ACTION_MENU'})
     .map(function(a) {
         return {iconClass: a.iconClass, id: 'anythingUnique', text: a.title};
     }).value();
```

I've changed your filter a little, but you could do it your way if you wanted, and I've used a functional approach with chaining, but you could do it imperatively if that makes you more comfortable. Map effectively replaces an array element with the returned element.